Visual Studio Code wrap comment with header and footer
Is there a way to highlight a block of code and add a header and footer comment at same time?  For example:
**<!-- sidebar section -->**
<div id="sidebar">
..........
</div>
**<!-- sidebar section -->**


And you want to extract the id from the first line when you do this?  Or is it okay to type that later?  I assume the **'s are not to appear in the final form - as they are not valid comments.

Try this: first make a snippet with this:
"wrap element": {
    "prefix": "_cc2",    // you won't be using this
    "body": [
            "$BLOCK_COMMENT_START $1 section $BLOCK_COMMENT_END",
            "$CLIPBOARD",
            "$BLOCK_COMMENT_START $1 section $BLOCK_COMMENT_END",               
    ],
    "description": "Wrap an html element in comments"
}

Then make a keybinding (in your keybindings.json file) with this:
{
  "key": "alt+c",  "command": "runCommands",
  "args": {
    "commands": [
      "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",
      {
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "args": {
          "name": "wrap element"    // use the snippet from above
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly && editorLangId == html"
}


If you want those **'s you could add them to the snippet.
If you want to extract the id sidebar, that is much harder and probably would require an extension to accomplish.
If you were creating the element originally I think you could use comment filters to do what you want, but your element is already there and you are trying to modify it.

If you are creating this element and you want to wrap it with comments, then make these two settings (in your settings.json):
  "emmet.preferences": {
    "filter.commentAfter": "\n<!-- [ID][CLASS]: section -->",
    "filter.commentBefore": "<!-- [ID][CLASS]: section -->\n"
  },

  "emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
    "html": {
      "filters": "c"
    }
  },

then when you make the element by using .sidebar and tab/enter on the emmet suggestion for .sidebar you will get
<!-- sidebar: section -->
<div class="sidebar"></div>
<!-- sidebar: section -->


